# Why am I still getting 'undefined reference' linker errors when using SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I've already looked at every other page on stack overflow directly relating to this error.

I am doing everything I could, but I am still getting this error

> undefined reference to `SDL_Init'

This is the build log:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ testproject - Debug ]----------"
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Andre/Documents/CodeLiteWorkspace/testproject'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/g++.exe -o ./Debug/testproject @"testproject.txt" -L.
./Debug/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/testproject] Error 1
testproject.mk:82: recipe for target 'Debug/testproject' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Andre/Documents/CodeLiteWorkspace/testproject'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
====2 errors, 0 warnings====
```

These are the build options I'm using

```
-std=c++11;-IC:\SDL2\include -LC:\SDL2\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

And I know that everything (compiler and library files) are all 64-bit binaries. I've found out that it gives me the same error but instead of `SDL_Init` it says `WinMain` if I were to use the normal `int main()` entry function, so now I am using `int WinMain()`, which removed that error. So now my code simply consists of

```
extern "C"{
    #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
}

int WinMain(){
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    return 0;
}
```

and if I comment out the `SDL_Init` function the program has no build errors but doesn't do anything.

Does anyone know if this has to do with the fact that I'm using a slightly different compiler? Also, I'm not sure, but from the build log it looks like it's not actually using the build options I supplied it (I'm using an IDE so the program manages that). Lastly, if anyone knows why it wants me to use `WinMain` and not the regular main function, and tell me what to change to fix that, that would be appreciated.

makefile:

```
##
## Auto Generated makefile by CodeLite IDE
## any manual changes will be erased      
##
## Debug
ProjectName            :=testproject
ConfigurationName      :=Debug
WorkspacePath          :=C:/Users/Andre/Documents/CodeLiteWorkspace
ProjectPath            :=C:/Users/Andre/Documents/CodeLiteWorkspace/testproject
IntermediateDirectory  :=./Debug
OutDir                 := $(IntermediateDirectory)
CurrentFileName        :=
CurrentFilePath        :=
CurrentFileFullPath    :=
User                   :=Andrew900460
Date                   :=20/09/2018
CodeLitePath           :="C:/Program Files/CodeLite"
LinkerName             :=C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/g++.exe
SharedObjectLinkerName :=C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/g++.exe -shared -fPIC
ObjectSuffix           :=.o
DependSuffix           :=.o.d
PreprocessSuffix       :=.i
DebugSwitch            :=-g 
IncludeSwitch          :=-I
LibrarySwitch          :=-l
OutputSwitch           :=-o 
LibraryPathSwitch      :=-L
PreprocessorSwitch     :=-D
SourceSwitch           :=-c 
OutputFile             :=$(IntermediateDirectory)/$(ProjectName)
Preprocessors          :=
ObjectSwitch           :=-o 
ArchiveOutputSwitch    := 
PreprocessOnlySwitch   :=-E
ObjectsFileList        :="testproject.txt"
PCHCompileFlags        :=
MakeDirCommand         :=makedir
RcCmpOptions           := 
RcCompilerName         :=C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/windres.exe
LinkOptions            :=  
IncludePath            :=  $(IncludeSwitch). 
IncludePCH             := 
RcIncludePath          := 
Libs                   := 
ArLibs                 :=  
LibPath                := $(LibraryPathSwitch). 

##
## Common variables
## AR, CXX, CC, AS, CXXFLAGS and CFLAGS can be overriden using an environment variables
##
AR       := C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/ar.exe rcu
CXX      := C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/g++.exe
CC       := C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/gcc.exe
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -IC:\SDL2\include -Dmain=SDL_main -LC:\SDL2\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows  $(Preprocessors)
CFLAGS   := -g -O0 -Wall  $(Preprocessors)
ASFLAGS  := 
AS       := C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/as.exe


##
## User defined environment variables
##
CodeLiteDir:=C:\Program Files\CodeLite
Objects0=$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp$(ObjectSuffix) 



Objects=$(Objects0) 

##
## Main Build Targets 
##
.PHONY: all clean PreBuild PrePreBuild PostBuild MakeIntermediateDirs
all: $(OutputFile)

$(OutputFile): $(IntermediateDirectory)/.d $(Objects) 
    @$(MakeDirCommand) $(@D)
    @echo "" > $(IntermediateDirectory)/.d
    @echo $(Objects0)  > $(ObjectsFileList)
    $(LinkerName) $(OutputSwitch)$(OutputFile) @$(ObjectsFileList) $(LibPath) $(Libs) $(LinkOptions)

MakeIntermediateDirs:
    @$(MakeDirCommand) "./Debug"


$(IntermediateDirectory)/.d:
    @$(MakeDirCommand) "./Debug"

PreBuild:


##
## Objects
##
$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp$(ObjectSuffix): main.cpp $(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp$(DependSuffix)
    $(CXX) $(IncludePCH) $(SourceSwitch) "C:/Users/Andre/Documents/CodeLiteWorkspace/testproject/main.cpp" $(CXXFLAGS) $(ObjectSwitch)$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp$(ObjectSuffix) $(IncludePath)
$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp$(DependSuffix): main.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(IncludePCH) $(IncludePath) -MG -MP -MT$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp$(ObjectSuffix) -MF$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp$(DependSuffix) -MM main.cpp

$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp$(PreprocessSuffix): main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(IncludePCH) $(IncludePath) $(PreprocessOnlySwitch) $(OutputSwitch) $(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp$(PreprocessSuffix) main.cpp


-include $(IntermediateDirectory)/*$(DependSuffix)
##
## Clean
##
clean:
    $(RM) -r ./Debug/
```

Comment: Why is there a `;` in your build options?

Comment: Oh that's because of the ide I'm using. It has a list of checkboxes for different build options, and then a spot where you can type in your own options. And when you use the checkboxes it puts semicolons after each box you've checked

Comment: also, somtimes when I build, it lists all the build options before the error in the log, and most other times it doesn't, like the one I pasted here

Comment: Please, post also your makefile.

Comment: it's a bit long but ok. I'm gonna put it at the bottom of the post

Comment: Your compiler seem to be targeting x64. Are you sure you use x64 SDL?

Comment: I'm very sure of it, there is that 1% chance though that I might be wrong, but. Also I was seeing if I could get it to work by doing this through a bat file and it successfully compiles the exe with the "SDL_Init" function in main, and to make sure it actually called it I put in a couple cout calls before and after it. So it must be something with the IDE not doing what I did in the bat file I made.

Answer (score 1):

You've added linking options to `CXXFLAGS` - where they don't belong - but not to `LibPath`, `Libs` or `LinkOptions`. So you have linker options specified at compilation phase (which does nothing, as no linking is performed), but don't have them on linking phase.

"Logically" correct setting would be

```
Libs:=-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
LibPath:=-LC:\SDL2\lib -L.
LinkOptions:=-Wl,-subsystem,windows -mwindows
```

(not sure SDL2main should be there as it is not clear if you use it, as you have `WinMain` and not `main`/`SDL_main`)

Also, you literally asked for problems with `-w` option, so you shouldn't be surprised. If you don't want extra problems, don't prevent compiler to help you, and even better - ask for more of its help with at least `-Wall`.